# How do I set all Gmail web views to dark? (List view is good but mail content and settings are not)

Tags: gmail, gmail-themes

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

I found that there are quite few options I can select in gmail web version.

What I expect:

I hope to let the view to follow OS's appearance. Light in day time and dark in night.

If it's not possible, I hope to make it always dark.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Comment: Questions should be specific. Please share what you have tried besides selecting the built-in Dark Gmail theme, and be clear about the solution you are looking for. If you are looking for a software recommendation, the might better ask the question on [softwarerecs.se]. If you are looking to play with the operating system settings, the question might be better suited for [su], or the sites related to the operating system that you are using, like [unix.se], [apple.se], [ubuntu.se]. It would be nice if you try a web browser extension, to handle user styles / user scripts.

Answer (score 1):

One can use:

- chrome://flags/ : `#enable-force-dark`
- [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) Chrome or Firefox extension: I believe it allows to turn on dark mode for specific websites.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. I turn this to Enabled.